# flash player error on specific network?

Tags: windows-7, flash-player

I have a customer that insists that when he tries to watch videos online, he gets a flash player error that says the flash player needs to be installed.

It prevents the videos from playing and he's had his computer in our shop several time in the last week but while its in our office all videos work just fine with no issues whatsoever.

I have installed the latest flash player twice to make sure it was the latest version and from all appearances it works just fine. I also checked for virus activity and that came back clean. What could cause this?

The computer is running windows 7

Comment: We need more info. about the actual error. Is the plugin itself crashing? If so, does it crash on a particular site or on all sites with flash? If the problem manifests itself only at his home, you'll probably need to go on site to see it in action and diagnose it properly.

Comment: It seems like the plugin crashes and he claims it does it on all sites. Would something on his personal network cause this? I offered to do remote support next time it happened so I could see the error so I may be able to get more info soon. I dint no if this was a know problem with an easy fix or not.

Comment: I've never seen it, but possibly someone else has. Maybe something's messing with the video streams and the malformed data is causing the plugin to crash? Given the lack of information, who knows...

Comment: ok ill try to get more info

Comment: Which operating system is Flash Player running on?

Comment: its running windows 7

Comment: i updated with what the error says

Comment: Does this happen with all browsers? Can you ask him to download a flash file and see if it crashes when run locally and over the net, and locally with no network (ie plug the network plug). Is broswer up to date?

Comment: No it doesnt @DaveRook Had him try chrome and it works fine... Put that as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be browser related (assuming you are using Internet Explorer). Try a different browser like Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox.